# После того как отнял число после .split() не получается применить .join()

Tags: javascript

```js
let x = '10:45'
let s = x.split(':')
         .reduceRight((a)=>a-45)
         .join(':')
console.log(s)
```

почему не работает join()

Comment: join - метод массива, если он не работает, значит reduceRight возвращает не массив

Comment: и как реализовать этот код правильно? нужно перед join превратить в строку?

Comment: @Vahan Muradyan метод `reduceRight` приводит строку к одному значению.

Comment: @Vahan Muradyan Добавил ответ с работой в 24 часа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы совсем не хотите использовать параметр `Date`, а хотите работать со строкой, то используйте перевод в секунды. 
Работает и в том случае, если отнимаете от времени, к примеру, 0:30

```js
let x = '10:45';
let s = x.split(':');
let minus = 55; // Переводим 45 минут в секунды.
let TimeinSec = (s[0] * 3600) + (s[1] * 60) - (minus * 60); // Переводим время в секунды и отнимаем 45 минут в секундах.
if (TimeinSec < 0){ //Если получилось отрицательное число, то отнимаем от 24 часов.
    TimeinSec = (24 * 3600) + TimeinSec; // Плюс, так как, если TimeinSec < 0, то число отрицательное.
}
var h = TimeinSec/3600 ^ 0 ; // Переводим обратно в часы и минуты (часов)
var m = (TimeinSec-h*3600)/60 ^ 0 ; // Переводим обратно в часы и минуты (минут)
let NewTime = h + ':' + m; // Канкатенация в одну строку.

console.log(NewTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

Только я не понимаю, что из этого должно получиться

```js
let x = '10:45'
let s = x.split(':')
  .reverse()
  .map((a) => a - 45)
  .reverse()
  .join(':')
console.log(s)
```

Не спрашивайте почему я написал `.reverse().map().reverse()`,
это эмуляция того что хотел автор вопроса `reduceRight`

**UPD** надо было с самого начала и спрашивать: Как реализовать часы?

```js
class Clock {
  constructor() {
    this.date = new Date()
    this.show()
  }
  increment(min) {
    this.date.setMilliseconds(this.date.getMilliseconds() + min * 60 * 1000)
    this.show()
  }
  decrement(min) {
    this.date.setMilliseconds(this.date.getMilliseconds() - min * 60 * 1000)
    this.show()
  }
  show() {
    console.log(this.date.toLocaleTimeString(undefined,
      {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' })
    )
  }
}

const time = new Clock()

time.increment(10)
time.decrement(45)
time.increment(45)
time.decrement(10)
```

Comment: должно получиться 10:0 или если меньше 0 должно быть скажем 9:15

Comment: @VahanMuradyan если вы вы от `ЧЧ:ММ` отнимаете 45 минут, то так и задавайте свой вопрос.

Comment: @VahanMuradyan всё равно не ясна конечная цель. От 45 отнимется 10 в первом проходе и всё. Будет 35. Каким образом 9 должно получится? Задача не описана. В комментах к вопросу, впрочем, ответ на сам вопрос дали. `join` работает с массивами.